# Evernote API & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, evernote

I am trying to integrate the Evernote API into my laravel web app I am working on, but with the new PHP SDK there is limited documentation. When I try to use composer to install it I get an error. I'm somewhat new to composer so I may just be missing something.

The command it says to use is:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ composer require evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php dev-master
```

I've tried it in 3 different spots, my home directory (~), my app's directory, as well as within the evernote download. The first 2 give me the error:

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]
```

Could not parse version constraint @dev-master: Invalid version string "@dev-master"

and when i run within the evernote download folder, I get:

```
 - The requested package evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php 2.0 could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try omitting the version string when running composer:

```
composer require evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php
```

... And you have to do it from your app's root (where `composer.json` is)

**EDIT**:

See the comments to this answer. The problem was an earlier attempt to run a command with a version string of `@dev-master`, which then was in `composer.json`. Removing the at-symbol solved the problem.

Comment: I get the same exact error

      [UnexpectedValueException]                                                            
  Could not parse version constraint @dev-master: Invalid version string "@dev-master"

Comment: Ah. What's the content of your `composer.json`? I suspect that you might have a line saying `"evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php":"@dev-master"` which really should be `"evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php":"dev-master"`.

Comment: Awesome that did it, now the last thing im unsure about is where do i put the code `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Here is the documentation if it helps get context https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php

Comment: If you're using Laravel, that's already done for you :o) So you should be ready to just new up a `\Evernote\Client` instance.